# new dataframe column based on dictionary and str.contains()

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe `df` column `new_col`, placing the key value `k` of a dictionary `my_dict`, if some specific column `col_1` contains some string that is inside the dictionary values `v`, ( using regex character + join() ).

I did this correctly by iterating the dictionary, and making consecutive boolean filters. But I would like a more elegant solution. This was my start, but is not correct:

```
df['new_col'] = [k for k,v in my_dict.items() for x in df['col_1'].values if x.str.contains('|'.join(v))]
```

It seems that the error is due to different length of the dataframe and the dictionary.

Edit as requested:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['Some Transfer', 'Some Deposit', 'Some Dividend', 'Adj Shares Fee']})`

```
            col_1
0   Some Transfer
1    Some Deposit
2   Some Dividend
3  Adj Shares Fee
```

`my_dict = {'transfer':['Transfer', 'Deposit'],'dividend':['Dividend'],'shares fee':['Adj Shares']}`

`df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: "|".join((k for (k,v) in my_dict.items() if v in x)))`

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.contains()` works with a regular expression but it is meant for a column wise operation. You need to go through all the values of your dictionary. I don't know if there's a easy way to use it, maybe something like:

```
mx = [df.col_1.str.contains('|'.join(v)) for v in my_dict.values()]
df['new_col'] = np.array(list(my_dict.keys()))[np.argmax(mx,axis=0)]
```

Another way is to use `re` and adapt the code you have:

```
import re
df['new_col'] = df.col_1.apply(lambda x:[k for k,v in my_dict.items() if re.search('|'.join(v),x)][0])

    col_1   new_col
0   Some Transfer   transfer
1   Some Deposit    transfer
2   Some Dividend   dividend
3   Adj Shares Fee  shares fee
```

Comment: thks. good solution. the only problem is that when the string is not found, it is returning the first dict key. (talking about the first solution)

Comment: hey.. sounds like a moving goal post. you can add to the numpy code to do for example ```df['new_col'][~np.array(mx).any(axis=0)] = np.nan``` , this will add nan for rows that don't have a match

Comment: sorry, but I didnt understand how to add this line to the code. is it a second line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.apply()` on the column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':['Some Transfer', 'Some Deposit', 'Some Dividend', 'Adj Shares Fee']})
my_dict = {'transfer':['Transfer', 'Deposit'],'dividend':['Dividend'],'shares fee':['Adj Shares']}
```

So, because your dictionary has a *list* of entries for each key, one way to deal with it is to invert the dictionary so that the category is the value:

```
new_dict = {}
for key,val in my_dict.items():
    for v in val:
        new_dict[v] = key
```

Then the original construction I posted will work:

```
df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: "|".join( (v for (k,v) in new_dict.items() if k in x) ) )
```

Separately, if you wanted to be more flexible and deal with say ignoring the case you can use the `re` library as an alternative:

```
import re
df['new_col'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: "|".join( (v for (k,v) in new_dict.items() if re.search(k, x, flags=re.IGNORECASE) ) ) )

print(df)
            col_1     new_col
0   Some Transfer    transfer
1    Some Deposit    transfer
2   Some Dividend    dividend
3  Adj Shares Fee  shares fee
```

Comment: Thank you first. But I've got the error: `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`

Comment: Sorry... I had accidentally forgotten rename my dictionary from `d` to `my_dict`.  If that doesn't fix it, maybe edit the question to include a sample `df` and `my_dict`.

Comment: I modified the answer based on your update.

Comment: If the dict now has 1 ket for 1 value, why I still need to use "|".join()?

Comment: That's only there in case it's possible that you might match more than one key, which is possibly more general than you need then. It wasn't quite clear to me why you had the "|" in the original question, so that was my guess as to what you meant.